# Nest.js GraphQL Field Resolver

Tags: graphql, nestjs

my question is more about how to realize this. I didn't find answer inside docs so ask you);

For example:

- I have 2 entity User and Blog;
- User has Blog as one to many relation;
- My query for User looks like:

```
query {
    me {
        firstName
        lastName
        blogs {
            title
            description
        }
    }
}
```

In Nest.js code I have Resolver:

```js
@Resolver(() => UserEntity)
class UserResolver {
    @Query(() => User)
    me() {
        ...
    }

    @ResolveField(() => [BlogEntity])
    blogs() {
        ...
    }
}
```

But what if we try to change our query to this:

```
query {
    me {
        firstName
        lastName
        blogs {
            title
            description
            user {
                id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question: Can we delegate ResolveField to another resolver (For example BlogResolver)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can add ResolveField decorator to the BlogResolver for cycle structures

```
@Resolver(() => BlogEntity)
class BlogResolver {

    @ResolveField(() => [UserEntity])
    user() {
        ...
    }
}
```